# Issue in copying rows from one table to another

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am implementing a request mechanism where the user have to approve a request. For that i have implemented a temporary table and main table. Initially when the request is added the data will be inserted to the  temporary table, on approval it will be copied to the main table.

The issue is there will be more than 5k rows to be moved to the main table after approval + another 3-5 row for each row in the detail table (stores the details).
My current implementation is like this

```
//Get the rows from temporary table (batch_temp)
    //Loop through the data
        //Insert the data to the main table (batch_main) and return the id 
        //Get the details row from the temporary detail table (batch_temp_detail) using detail_tempid
            //Loop through the data
                //Insert the details to the detail table (batch_main_detail) with the main table id amount_id
            //End Loop  
    //End Loop
```

But this implementation would take atleast 20k queries. Is there any better ways to implement the same.

I tried to create a sqlfiddle but was unable to create one. So i have pasted the query in [pgsql.privatepaste.com](https://pgsql.privatepaste.com/7ac2109997)

Comment: Have you tried select into?

Comment: I haven't tried `SELECT INTO` but i have read the docs. From that i understood `SELECT INTO` will return void. But i need the amount_id from batch_main to insert the corresponding data to batch_main_detail.

Comment: Do you have a field that allow you to mark relation of records from temporary table and main table ? If you have, I think you can do your task with 2 queries, show me your table structures.

Comment: @Tarzan i have attached the link to the table structure in the question. Please check that. And in that structure `batchid` is the relation connecting the rows in main table and temp table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry that I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL. My solution is in MySQL, I hope it can help since if they (MySQL & PostgreSQL) are same.

First, we should add 1 more field into your *batch_main* table to track the origin *batch_temp* record for each *batch_main* record.

```
ALTER TABLE `batch_main`
    ADD COLUMN tempid bigint;
```

Then, on approval, we will insert 5k rows by 1 query:

```
INSERT INTO batch_main
    (batchid, userid, amount, tempid)
    SELECT batchid, userid, amount, amount_id FROM batch_temp;
```

So, with each new batch_main record we have its origin *batch_temp* record's id. Then, insert the detail records

```
INSERT INTO `batch_main_detail`
    (detail_amount, detail_mainid)
    SELECT
        btd.detail_amount, bm.amount_id
        FROM 
            batch_temp_detail `btd`
            INNER JOIN batch_main `bm` ON btd.detail_tempid = bm.tempid
```

Done!

P/S:
I'm confuse a bit about the way you name your fields, and since I do not know about PostgreSQL and by looking into your syntax, can you use same sequence for primary key of both table *batch_temp* & *batch_main*? If you can, it's no need to add 1 more field.

Hope this help,

Answer (score 0):

Simply need to update your Schema. Instead of having two tables: one `main` and one `temporary`, you should have all the data in main table, but have a flag which indicates whether a certain record is approved or no. Initially it will be set to false, and once approved it will simply be set to true and then the data can display on your website etc. That way you will not need to `write` the data two times, or even have to move it from one table to another

Comment: Actually the table i have given is only a sample structure, both tables contains contains some more fields than that.

Comment: Also there are some complexities in the calculations. Some of the rows in the temporary will not be copied to the main table... it have to be added to another table.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified RDBMS you are using, but good old INSERT with SELECT in it must do the trick in one command:

```
insert main (field1,...,fieldN) select field1,...,fieldN from temporary
```